# vagrant ssh agent forwarding only works for inline commands?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-agent

I've added agent forwarding to my vagrant file, and now when I run `vagrant ssh -c 'ssh-add -l'` I see a list of ssh keys, which is correct. However, when I run `vagrant ssh` to connect and then run `ssh-add -l`, I don't see any keys! It looks like the forwarding only works for commands included as part of the initial call, otherwise it doesn't forward them.

What is going on here? How do I get it to forward the keys consistently, for all ssh connections to vagrant?

Comment: Can't reproduce that.

Comment: I confirm that with Vagrant 1.4.0 Have you resolved that?

Comment: Upgraded to 1.8.1, had no effect tough